# the stories (were/are) created by the teenagers

Tags: past-participles

> The public will be able to listen to the stories **created** by the teenagers and look at the symbolic art works inside these wooden dolls, beautifully **carved** by the Dublin Woodturners’ Association. [The Irish Times](http://www.irishtimes.com/life-and-style/health-family/teens-in-hospital-explore-their-creative-lives-1.2566359)

Aren't *created* & *covered* past participles in the above sentence? Shouldn't we use *to be verbs* with them because the above clauses are passive voice?

> - the stories **are** created by the teenagers ...
> - beautifully **was** carved by the Dublin ...

Comment: You would be adding a second tensed verb if you were to do that, making an independent clause which cannot be the object of "listen to". But you could use a relative: "*which* were created by the teenagers ... *which* were beautifully carved by ...."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentences are correct as they are. This attributive use of the participle is very common.

Simply said, you can use a participle in much the same way as an adjective (it is not completely the same, but I won't go into the details now.)

You can use adjectives to describe a noun:

> I own a *blue* car.

Instead, I can use a *present participle*:

> I'm in a *moving* car.

Or I can use a *past participle*:

> I'm looking at a *painted* car.

This is exactly how those two particples are used in your sentences.

They talk about stories *created* (by someone) and art works *carved* by someone.

As for your alternative version, you can rewrite the sentences but not as you did it. You need to add more:

> The public will be able to listen to the stories *that were* created by the teenagers and look at the symbolic art works inside these wooden dolls, *that were* beautifully carved by the Dublin Woodturners’ Association.

Instead of *were* you can use *are*, the difference between those is a completely different topic.

Do note that *art works* is plural so your suggestion of singular *was* would bot work!